mvn command line to pull/copy-local an "ext: 'pom' artifact
When I need to pull a dependency directly via the command line (and it is a .jar)
I run something like this:
/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.8.2/bin/mvn  dependency:copy -Dartifact=org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.17.0  -DoutputDirectory=. -U

and I get an output like this:
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.17.0:jar
Downloading from artifactory: /repo/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.17.0/commons-lang3-3.17.0.jar
Downloaded from artifactory: /repo/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.17.0/commons-lang3-3.17.0.jar (674 kB at 691 kB/s)
[INFO] Copying commons-lang3-3.17.0.jar to /(my-directory)/commons-lang3-3.17.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

aka, everything above works fine.
below is a "ext: 'pom'" artifact.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-verifier/9.44.0.Final
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-verifier
implementation group: 'org.drools', name: 'drools-verifier', version: '9.44.0.Final', ext: 'pom'

Taking the above syntax and runnning it (with different groupid/artifactid/version of course)
 /opt/maven/apache-maven-3.8.2/bin/mvn  dependency:copy   -Dartifact=org.drools:drools-verifier:9.44.0.Final -DoutputDirectory=. -U

it tries to pull down a .jar
repo/org/drools/drools-verifier/9.44.0.Final/drools-verifier-9.44.0.Final.jar

(which does not exist)
..
I tried using the '-Dpackaging=pom' argument:
 /opt/maven/apache-maven-3.8.2/bin/mvn  dependency:copy    -Dartifact=org.drools:drools-verifier:9.44.0.Final -Dpackaging=pom -DoutputDirectory=. -U

But that is failing as well.
Does anyone know the magic syntax to copy down a "pom" specific artifact?
...
"Extra"
"packaging type"
https://www.baeldung.com/maven-packaging-types#4-pom

First question: Why do you need to get the dependency via maven-dependency-plupgin?

Great.  a downvote for NO REASON.

I am not circumventing "normal" ways to pull dependencies.  My company does not allow developers to use public maven.  we use internal artifactory.  BUT, this internal-only sometimes has hiccups.  Where I am trying to validate that our local internal artifactory .. "cloned" public maven correctly.        I am having an issue with this specific (drools) file.  This is the quick manually download that I use to pull both copies and figure out if they are identical.
